# How do I go to the first/next build error in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: build, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using VSCode tasks to build Java and C++ projects.

When I compile, I would like to be able to immediately hit a keyboard shortcut, and then jump directly to the first/next build error, regardless if the file is open or not.

Is this behaviour available?

Answer (score -1):

If the error is in the problems view, <kbd>F8</kbd> jumps to the next error. This is the standard keybinding for the `editor.action.marker.nextInFiles` command

Comment: This does not open the file, it only jumps to the error in the current file.

Comment: Is the problem listed in the `problems` section? On VS Code 1.28 this definitely jumps to unopened files

Comment: Are you saying that pressing F8 definitely opens unopened files?

Comment: Yes, it will open the next error in the problems view (for an opened file or not)

Comment: Will pressing F8 with problems view closed still open the file? Just want to be clear incase I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Yes, you need to be focused on some editor. The standard keybinding is only enabled when there is an active, non-readonly editor. That's probably an oversight because I can't see why it wouldn't be enabled all the time

Comment: Nope this doesn't work. This is after more investigation, this is based on the problems system, and not compiler errors based on regex. If I don't have the language support plugin installed for the current language being compiled, this doesn't work.